# Is it possible to use the matched string in sed as an input to shell date command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, date, sed

I have a file with records having timestamp fields that include GMT offset. I want to use the `sed` command to replace the value on the record to a regular timestamp (without GMT offset).

For example:

```
`$date -d '2012/11/01 00:50:22 -0800' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
```

returns this value which is what I am looking to do:

```
2012-11-01 01:50:22
```

Except I want to perform that operation on every line of this file and apply the date command to the timestamp value. Here is a sample record:

```
"SB","6GV96644X48128125","","","","T0006",2012/10/03 13:08:43 -0700,"NJ"
```

Here is my code:

```
head -1 myfile | sed 's/,[0-9: /\-]\{25\},/,'"`date -d \1 '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`"',/
```

which doesn't work: it just ignores \1 and replaces the matched pattern with today's date:

```
"SB","6GV96644X48128125","","","","T0006",2012-11-14 01:00:00,"NJ"
```

I hoped that `\1` would result in the matched patterns be passed to the date function and return a regular timestamp value (as in the example I provided above showing how the date functions applies the GMT offset and returns a regular stimestamp string) and would replace the old value on the record.

Comment: "Just replaces the matched pattern ..." . that means it isn't matching your reg exp. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `awk` instead.  For example:

```
awk '{cmd="date -d \""$7"\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"";
    cmd | getline k; $7=k; print}' FS=, OFS=, myFile
```

This will replace the 7th field with the results of running the date command on the original contents of the 7th field.

Comment: Thanks sooo much.  One problem that I hope you can help me with:  it seems that it doesn't recognize the "" as a field in the record. some fields may have null value ("") on some records.  Is there any way to tell it to use "," as a field delim so that it will pick the right value for $7:  "SB","6GV96644X48128125","","","","T0006",2012/10/03 13:08:43 -0700,"NJ"             really appreciate your help

Comment: With `FS=,`, the fields will be determined by the commas.  `""` should not be treated specially.

Comment: sorry I had left out the FS=,.  It works and it changes the date.  However, it took all the commas out!  the resulting record had no , as field separator.  Anyway to get around that?  Also, is it possible to make the $7 (the field#) a shell variable? would replace $7 with ${datefldnum}  do the trick? Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to add `OFS=,` to keep the commas.  My apologies for omitting that from the answer. Edited.

Comment: It works beautifully!  Thanks soooooooooo much.  Really appreciate all your help and your follow up answers.

Answer (score 0):

In `sed`:

```
head -1 datefile |
  sed '
    # handle % in input correctly
    s/%/%%/g
    # execute date(1) command
    s/\(.*,\)\([0-9: /\-]\{25\}\)\(,.*\)/'"date -d '\2' '+\1%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\3'"'/e'
  '
```

Comment: Note that this isn't portable: the `e` flag to the `s` command is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){6})([^,]*)(.*)/printf "%s%s%s" '\''\1'\'' $(date -d '\''\3'\'' '\''+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\'') '\''\4'\''/e;q' file
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
head -1 datefile | sed -e 's?\(..\)/\(..\)/\(.... ..:..:..\)?'"date -d '\2/\1/\3' '+%s'"'?e'
```

Comment: Note that this isn't portable: the `e` flag to the `s` command is a GNU extension.